# Python: Regex code not able to remove ' and - from text

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I have a chunk of text a sample of which I included below.

```
'tis too true! How smart a lash that 
speech doth give my conscience! The harlot's cheek beautied with plastering art Is not more ugly to the thing
```

I want to get rid of all punctuation that is not ".?!".  And I thought I did so using the code below:

```
hamsplits2 = re.sub(r'[^[a-z.?!\s]]', "", hamsplits1) # substitute any character that is not what's in box
```

But the code doesn't seem to work because when I print(hamsplits2) I still get apostrophes and dashes.

```
how smart a lash that 
speech doth give my conscience! the harlot's cheek beautied with plastering art is not more ugly to the
```

What is wrong with my regex causing it not to remove apostrophes and dashes?

Answer (score 3):

Your `[^[a-z.?!\s]]` regex is a "malformed" pattern. It contains two parts, `[^[a-z.?!\s]` and a `]` atoms. `[^[a-z.?!\s]` is a negated character class that matches any char but `[`, lowercase letter, `.`, `?`, `!` and whitespace and `]` matches a literal `]`. So, it matches two-char combinations like `]]`, `1]`, etc.

You can use

```py
hamsplits2 = re.sub(r'[^\w\s.?!]|_', '', hamsplits1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2guH6/2)

The `[^\w\s.?!]|_` regex matches either a punctuation char other than `.`, `?` and `!` and `_`,  or a `_` (that is because `\w` matches an underscore, not only letters and digits).

**More details**

- `[^\w\s.?!]` - a negated character class matching any char other than a word char (`\w`), a whitespace char (`\s`), `.`, `?` and `!`
- `|` - or
- `_` - an underscore.

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation.  can you elaborate on why my original attempt did not work?

Comment: @PineNuts0 I added the explanation as the first paragraph.

Comment: I see ... but why does my original regex not match - and ' ?

Comment: @PineNuts0 It matches **two**-char combinations. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dgW4rp/1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the first `]` so it's treated as a literal character rather than terminating the first `[`.

```
hamsplits2 = re.sub(r'[^[a-z.?!\s\]]', "", hamsplits1)
```

If you didn't mean to include `[` and `]` in the set of punctuation that should be kept, take them both out of the character set:

```
hamsplits2 = re.sub(r'[^a-z.?!\s]', "", hamsplits1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex: `[^\w\d\.\?\!\s]`, meaning not word, digit nor `.?!` nor spaces.